# ImportError: cannot import name 'regex_replace'

Tags: python, tensorflow-hub

I'm totally new to python, while run my program i got an error..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_hub/tf_v1.py", line 29, in <module>
    from tensorflow.compat.v1 import *  
ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow.compat'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "train.py", line 5, in <module>
        import tensorflow_hub as hub
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_hub/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
        from tensorflow_hub.estimator import LatestModuleExporter
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_hub/estimator.py", line 25, in <module>
        from tensorflow_hub import tf_utils
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_hub/tf_utils.py", line 28, in <module>
        from tensorflow_hub import tf_v1
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_hub/tf_v1.py", line 63, in <module>
        from tensorflow import regex_replace
    ImportError: cannot import name 'regex_replace'
```

my `train.py` is

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import json
import pickle
import urllib

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer

print(tf.__version__)
```

without import `tensorflow_hub` it's working fine.. but for my algorithm it must.. I searched many links but I couldn't get proper solution.  please give me small hint to solve my problem..

Comment: I just tried to run your code.  I had an existing venv with numpy and pandas.  I did 'pip install tensorflow' and 'pip install tensorflow_hub' and the code works for me.  I get result "1.13.1".  I tried "from tensorflow import regex_replace" on its own at the Python prompt, and that worked too.  I'm thinking that there's some version thing going on.  What version of TF are you using?

Comment: im using version 1.5 sir

Comment: That seems pretty old, if it's 1.5 vs 1.13 - maybe you need to upgrade your version.

Comment: could you please give me a hint how to upgrade or install 1.13.1

Comment: sir after upgrade i got `F tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:37] The TensorFlow library was compiled to use AVX instructions, but these aren't available on your machine.
Aborted` error

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip says: "Starting with TensorFlow 1.6, binaries use AVX instructions which may not run on older CPUs."  On the other hand, tensorflow_hub will not work with anything that old (regex_replace is just a symptom, there harder reasons). If you don't have a machine with AVX available,  and running on colab.research.google.com does not address your needs, it appears you will have to build your own TF binaries. Please see https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source or https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=compile+tensorflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try upgrading the tensorflow module. It worked for me.
Upgrade using the following command.
`pip install --upgrade tensorflow`

Comment: Currently tensorflow-hub requires version 1.7 or newer of tensorflow.
https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/installation